# .NET DLR and SecurityException's

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime, securityexception

What are the mandatory `PermissionSet` items that the DLR requires in order to function correctly?

We've enabled the DLR in our sandboxed scripting environment. But some code like the following...

```
dynamic foo = someobject
foo.FooBar();
```

... just results in a rather vague and "unfinished"-looking exception being thrown, as follows:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Scripting.Assemblies.WorkflowScriptImplementation.Test()
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Scripting.Assemblies.WorkflowScriptImplementation.__action_activity_4397110c5d7141a6802a070d3b942b77()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Scripting.WorkflowScriptProxy.Invoke(String method_name)
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Execution.Executors.ActionActivityExecutor.Execute(WorkflowInstance wi, ActionActivity activity)
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Execution.ActivityExecutorBase.Execute(WorkflowInstance wi, Activity activity)
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Execution.WorkflowExecutor.ExecuteActivity(WorkflowInstance wi, Activity activity)
   at AcmeCorp.AcmeRocket.Workflow.Execution.WorkflowExecutor.Execute(WorkflowInstance wi, Nullable`1 branch_index)
```

Normally `SecurityException`'s include a host of detail specifying precisely which permissions caused it to fail, but in this case we are not getting that - very annoying.

PS: If I run the same test with our sandbox temporarily granted a `PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)` then the problem goes away. But obviously we really want to lock it down to the very specific set of permissions that the DLR requires.

PPS: The current (failing) PermissionSet is created as follows:

```
var ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
ps.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
ps.AddPermission(new ReflectionPermission(ReflectionPermissionFlag.RestrictedMemberAccess));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting a more detailed security exception is that it is being read in a context that has restricted CAS permissions.  You can read the full exception details if you invoke its ToString method in a fully trusted context.

That said, I am unable to reproduce the same problem in a simple sandboxed AppDomain scenario, so I'm wondering if your exception is really due to DLR use.  What happens if you attempt to invoke the same method on a strongly typed target instance under the same permission set?

For example, I can repro a similar exception if the invoked method has a LinkDemand for an unrestricted permission set.  This problem can be seen, albeit with a different call stack, regardless of whether the invocation against a dynamic or strongly typed variable.

Comment: Sometimes a second opinion like this post is all it needs to find the solution. Turns out my assembly (that `someobject` originates from, i my example) was missing the token "AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute". I'm annoyed with myself that I didn't check and double-check this sooner.